# What is the best way to query the most recent entries in my access database?

Tags: ms-access

If I have one table for cognitive assessment and patients are added to the table as they come in from year to year, they will have multiple records in this table.

How do I run a query to pull all people from the patient information table (the entire cohort) and their corresponding cognitive information without duplicates (only pull the single most recent record from cognitive assessment)?

Comment: Use an autoincrement id column and select the top row for a specific patient sorted reverse on id.

Comment: I know what you mean by autoincrement ID, but can you elaborate on "select the top row...."? This query will have thousands of patients in it; we wouldn't be able to go patient-by-patient and select the correct one.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM patients ORDER BY id DESC WHERE patient.id = 123

Comment: Sorry, did you want the latest record for each patient not just a specific one?

Comment: Yes. The issue is that I have a few tables like the cognitive assessment table. So, I would want to pull all patients in the cohort (from the patient information table) and their single most recent entry from each of the secondary tables (cognitive, vitals, etc.)

Comment: Each table **should** have a Date field of some sort I'd assume?  The date of the office visit or assessment should be stored for billing purposes.  So, just do a SELECT Top 1 and ORDER BY DateField DESC.

Comment: Select top 1 keeps selecting only the top row in the table instead of the top row for each ID.

Comment: A simple way with 2 queries would be  1) prepare a query with patient id and the most recent date then  2) use a 2nd query to join that to your patient file on id and date to get the full current record.  If you want a single query you could use a subquery to do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a subquery to provide what you need

```
SELECT PatientEval.Patient, PatientEval.EvalDate, PatientEval.Eval
FROM PatientEval
WHERE (((PatientEval.EvalDate)=(select max(EvalDate) from PatientEval T where T.Patient=PatientEval.Patient)));
```